# Arduino heart rate sensor with buzzer

Tags: c++, arduino

so me and my friend bought a heart rate sensor for arduino board and we wanted to pair it with a buzzer, so everytime when a heartbeat is detected we hear a sound coming from a buzzer. I really don't know how to write a code for this so any help would be fantastic. We tried it last week but without success; we were unable to code it properly and buzzer didn't go off.

Comment: Try writing the code first. Then come back with *specific* question(s) about what you can't get working/don't understand. We're not here to teach you basic programming.

Comment: Code is nice, but an implementation plan or an approach would also work. Narrow the question down. The best way to do this is to break the problem down into the tasks that must be performed to set off the buzzer. If you don't know how to perform a task, break the task down more and more until you reach a point where you do know how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just looking for somewhere to start then I'd suggest with just getting the buzzer to go off at least once.  After that, make another project file and start trying to read input from the sensor.  To do this you're going to need to google a few things, like how the sensor sends data.  I'd be willing to bet it just sends a pulse down a wire to ur arduino, so you'll probably also have to look up 'how to read voltage input on arduino'.

The scope of you're question is too large to answer with code and I also don't want to take this learning experience from you.  As Jesper pointed out, once you have code (that either works or doesn't) come back and either update you're question or make a new one and we can go from there.

Here's a working example of an arduino taking an analog input and changing the blink rate of an LED accordingly.  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/AnalogInput

Arduinos can take both analog and digital input, so that's where you'll need to do some research on the heart rate sensor as the code will be different if it is digital.

Heres another site with beginner style tutorials for arduinos, it might be another nice spot for you to start this project:  https://programmingelectronics.com/arduino-tutorials-all/

I also don't know how you're buzzer works, but I've seen people have trouble with them before so if whatever you try doesn't work you might want to take a look at this:  https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Tone